# What exactly is meant by "clock rate" in the theory of relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, relativity

In posts concerned with special or general relativity there is occasional mentioning of "**clock rate**"; specificlally [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22clock+rate%22+%5Bspecial-relativity%5D), and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22clock+rate%22+%5Bgeneral-relativity%5D). It even comes up in [Einstein's own writings (in translation)](http://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/~searchResults?searchMode=advanced&context=-2&searchParam-SearchGroup=&lang=EN&searchText=%22clock+rate%22&sortField=Sort), though apparently only once.

What exactly is meant by "**clock rate**", in this context?

(For definiteness, please consider the clock $\mathcal A \equiv (A, t_{\mathcal A})$, consisting of

- an ordered set $A$ of [clock indications](http://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol2-trans/321?highlightText=%22clock%20indication%22), such as proto-typically ["*position of the small hand*"](http://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/~searchResults?searchMode=advanced&context=-2&searchParam-SearchGroup=&lang=EN&searchText=%22small+hand%22&sortField=Sort) and
- [clock readings](http://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/~searchResults?searchMode=quick&sortField=Sort&searchText=%22clock+reading%22&context=-2&sortField=Sort) $t_{\mathcal A} : A \rightarrow \mathbb R$ which are attributed to the indications;

and express some examples of values of its "clock rate".)

Comment: Strange. You asked and answered your own question, and to me it seems a lot of mathematical definition to simply say what an ideal clock measures as time passes, in its own coordinate system. Ideal: if it measures the same as our standard (in Paris) measures. If not there are some classical corrections to be made, but I don't think these kinds of errors are your question. What's the purpose of your question?

Comment: @Bob Bee: "_What's the purpose of your question?_" -- To point out that I haven't found a definition of "clock rate" spelt out in the literature; and to ask for a remedy. (The purpose of [my answer submitted below](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/318809) is to sketch a possible definition of "clock rate".) "_to simply say what an ideal clock measures as time passes, in its own coordinate system. Ideal: [...]._" -- Neither my question nor my answer make reference to "ideal clock"; but feel free to expand your suggestion into an answer, describing another possible definition of "clock rate"

Comment: No,I'll let you be with your question, not something I need answered.

Answer (score 0):

For any two distinct indications of the clock $\mathcal A$ under consideration, $A_j, A_q \in A$, a corresponding particular value of its clock rate can be evaluated as $$f^{\text{particular}}_{\mathcal A}[ \, \_j, \_q \, ] := \frac{(t_{\mathcal A}[ \, A_q \, ] - t_{\mathcal A}[ \, A_j \, ])}{\tau A[ \, \_j, \_q \, ]},$$

where $\tau A[ \, \_j, \_q \, ]$ is the duration of the participant whose indications are making up set $A$, from indication $A_j$ until indication $A_q$.

If certain additional requirements are satisfied, this particular clock rate value may be considered as average value, or representative value, of the clock rate of clock $\mathcal A$ between indications $A_j$ and $A_q$;
it may for instance be required that for any two indications $A_k$ and $A_p$ between indications $A_j$ and $A_q$ holds:

$$ \left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\right)^{\left(\frac{\tau A[ \, \_j, \_q \, ]}{\tau A[ \, \_k, \_p \, ]}\right)} \lt \left( \frac{f^{\text{particular}}_{\mathcal A}[ \, \_k, \_p \, ]}{f^{\text{particular}}_{\mathcal A}[ \, \_j, \_q \, ]} \right) \lt \left(\sqrt{2}\right)^{\left(\frac{\tau A[ \, \_j, \_q \, ]}{\tau A[ \, \_k, \_p \, ]}\right)}.$$

Moreover, if the limit exists

$$\text{lim}_{ \{ \tau A[ \, \_j, \_k \, ] \longrightarrow 0 \}}\left[ \, \frac{(t_{\mathcal A}[ \, A_k \, ] - t_{\mathcal A}[ \, A_j \, ])}{\tau A[ \, \_j, \_k \, ]} \, \right] $$

then it presents the value of instantaneous clock rate of clock $\mathcal A$ at indication $A_k$.