# Two simple, ticking clocks, one at the top, the other at the floor of a uniformly rigidly accelerating rocket. Which one ticked faster than the other?

Tags: special-relativity, experimental-physics, acceleration, terminology

In a (as good as) flat region let $P$ be the top and $Q$ be the floor of a (very thin) rocket; both accelerating uniformly, along the same spatial direction, $P$ ahead and $Q$ following behind "on the same straight line"; and, moreover, $P$ and $Q$ are remaining chrometrically rigid wrt. each other (as may be expected of top and floor of a sturdy rocket).

Therefore, as shown [here (for instance)](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/38377/an-accelerating-and-shrinking-train-in-special-relativity/63110#63110), the uniform constant acceleration of $P$ and the uniform constant acceleration of $Q$ have different non-zero magnitudes,

$$| \mathbf a_P | \lt | \mathbf a_Q |,$$

and it obtains the exact relation

$$ 1 \lt \left( \frac{| \mathbf a_Q |}{| \mathbf a_P |} \right) = \left( \frac{\tau^P_{(\circledR \, Q \, \circledR \, P)}}{\tau^Q_{(\circledR \, P \, \circledR \, Q)}} \right) = \text{Exp}\Big[ \, \frac{| \mathbf a_P | \, \tau^P_{(\circledR \, Q \, \circledR \, P)}}{2 \, c} \, \Big]  = \text{Exp}\Big[ \, \frac{| \mathbf a_Q | \, \tau^Q_{(\circledR \, P \, \circledR \, Q)}}{2 \, c} \, \Big],$$

where
$\tau^P_{(\circledR \, Q \, \circledR \, P)}$ denotes $P$'s constant ping duration wrt. $Q$,
$\tau^Q_{(\circledR \, P \, \circledR \, Q)}$ denotes $Q$'s constant ping duration wrt. $P$, and
$c$ denotes the signal front speed wrt. any inertial system, of course.

Their mutual ping durations both being finite also fits the description that top $P$ and floor $Q$ of the rocket can always observe each other (at least in principle). Accordingly, let

- $P_{\ast}$ be one recognizable but otherwise arbitrary indication of $P$ (which might also be thought of as "$P$ stating and emitting a signal flash"),
- $Q_{(\circledR \, P \ast)}$ be $Q$'s corresponding indication of having received and reflected $P$'s signal indication $P_{\ast}$ (which might also be thought of as "$Q$'s ping echo of $P$'s signal flash"),
- $P_{(\circledR \, Q \, \circledR \, P \ast)}$ be $P$'s corresponding indication of having received and reflected $Q$'s ping echo of $P$'s signal indication,
- $Q_{(\circledR \, P \, \circledR \, Q \, \circledR \, P \ast)}$ in turn be $Q$'s indication of having received and reflected $P$'s ping echo of $Q$'s ping echo of $P$'s signal indication,

and so on.

Now, from the resulting ordered subset $\mathcal P \equiv \{ P_{\ast}, P_{(\circledR \, Q \, \circledR \, P \ast)}, \dots \}$ of $P$'s indications, as "ticks", a particular clock $\mathfrak P \equiv (\mathcal P, t_{\mathfrak P})$ can be produced by any particular assignment of readings, $t_{\mathfrak P} : \mathcal P \rightarrow \mathbb R$.

For the purpose of my question let's consider the following especially simple, even obvious assignment of readings with natural numbers as values:

$t_{\mathfrak P}[ \, P_{\ast} \, ] := 0$,
$t_{\mathfrak P}[ \, P_{(\circledR \, Q \, \circledR \, P \ast)} \, ] := 1$,
$t_{\mathfrak P}[ \, P_{(\circledR \, Q \, \circledR \, P \, \circledR \, Q \, \circledR \, P \ast)} \, ] := 2$,
and so on
(i.e. incrementing the reading $t_{\mathfrak P}$ by $1$ for each additional successive signal roundtrip observed by $P$).

Likewise, from the ordered subset $\mathcal Q \equiv \{ Q_{(\circledR \, P \ast)}, Q_{(\circledR \, P \, \circledR \, Q \, \circledR \, P \ast)}, \dots \}$ of $Q$'s indications, as "ticks", a particular clock $\mathfrak Q \equiv (\mathcal Q, t_{\mathfrak Q})$ can be produced by any particular assignment of readings, $t_{\mathfrak Q} : \mathcal Q \rightarrow \mathbb R$;
and let the assignment under consideration be likewise utterly simple:

$t_{\mathfrak Q}[ \, Q_{(\circledR \, P \ast)} \, ] := 0$,
$t_{\mathfrak Q}[ \, Q_{(\circledR \, P \, \circledR \, Q \, \circledR \, P \ast)} \, ] := 1$,
$t_{\mathfrak Q}[ \, Q_{(\circledR \, P \, \circledR \, Q \, \circledR \, P \, \circledR \, Q \, \circledR \, P \ast)} \, ] := 2$,
and so on
(incrementing the reading $t_{\mathfrak Q}$ by $1$ for each additional successive signal roundtrip observed by $Q$).

**My question:**

Which of these two clocks had been ticking faster than the other? --
clock $\mathfrak P$ counting the ping echo ticks $\mathcal P$ of the top $P$ of the rocket, or
clock $\mathfrak Q$ counting the ping echo ticks $\mathcal Q$ of the rocket floor $Q$ ?

Or: Were these two clocks ticking equally fast?

---

A note on comments:
It has been suggested (in a comment by @Felicia which meanwhile has been removed) that the problem stated in the above OP question has been analyzed and answered by R. Feynman. If so, would you please let us know the exact reference, and provide at least a sketch of the derivation.

Comment: I find your terminology very tedious to follow. Are you saying, in effect, that light bounces between P and Q, and that the ticks of one clock are the bounce events at P and the ticks of the other clock are the bounce events at Q?

Comment: @Marco Ocram: _"I find your terminology very tedious to follow."_ -- I strongly sympathize; but unfortunately: I'm not aware of any less tedious terminology (and corresponding notation) that is sufficiently expressive. _"[Do you mean] that light bounces between $P$ and $Q$, and that the ticks of one clock are the bounce events at $P$ and the ticks of the other clock are the bounce events at $Q$?"_ -- Roughly: yes. Being fussy: I mean only one sequence of successive pings (i.e. the most sparse case "light bouncing between $P$ and $Q$; and ... [contd.]

Comment: .@Marco Ocram: [2/2] ... and one "tick" of one clock (e.g. of the clock at the rocket top, $P$) is not exactly meant to be an entire _"bounce event"_ in which $P$ took part, but merely $P$'s specific share (portion, part ...) of such a _"bounce event"_; a.k.a. "$P$'s indication" at such an event.

Comment: I've removed a comment that should have been posted as an answer, and a reply to it. Please use comments to improve the question.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by specific share or portion. You seem to be saying that P emits a flash which bounces successively between Q and P. In effect, Q and P are the opposite ends of a light clock. Is that correct?

Comment: @Marco Ocram: _"I still don't understand what you mean by specific share or portion."_ -- Well, let's try to [do something about that](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/693862/12262)

Comment: @Marco Ocram: _"You seem to be saying that $P$ emits a flash which bounces successively between $Q$ and $P$."_ Correct. However: there are additional "geometric-kinematic" requirements on $P$ and $Q$, individually and in relation to each other. _"In effect, $Q$ and $P$ are the opposite ends of a light clock."_ -- The two ends of a light clock also bounce one flash off each other; yes-**but:** two ends of a light clock usually have to satisfy **very different** "geometric-kinematic" requirements than imposed on $P$ and $Q$ of my OP question, and ... [contd.]

Comment: @Marco Ocram: [2/2] ... and (the point of my OP question is): the clocks $\mathfrak P$ (produced from $P$'s bounce indications by assigning the readings $t_{\mathfrak P}$) and $\mathfrak Q$ (produced from $Q$'s bounce indications by assigning the readings $t_{\mathfrak Q}$) are to be considered as distinct, in relation to each other: I'm asking "Which of these **two clocks** is ticking faster than the other?". In contrast, any "light clock" is apparently being considered as one clock, as a whole.

Comment: Leaving aside the geometric-kinematic requirements for a moment, my understanding is that you have light signals bouncing between P and Q; you are taking the successive arrivals of light at P to be the ticks of P's clock and the successive arrivals of light at Q to be the ticks of Q's clock. Is that correct?

Comment: @Marco Ocram: _"[...] Is that correct?"_ -- **One** initial "flash" indication of $P$, denoted $P_{\ast}$ in the OP; followed by (or rather: initiating) **one** sequence of successive corresponding "bounce" indications of $Q$ and of $P$, alternatingly. (That's to say: **not** some arbitrarily large number of light signal sequences bouncing concurrently between $P$ and $Q$.) And yes: Those indications (set $\mathcal P$ of $P$'s bounce indications, and set $\mathcal Q$ of $Q$'s bounce indications) are taken as the "ticks" of clock $\mathfrak P$, and of clock $\mathfrak Q$, respectively.

Comment: It is late, I am tired and about to go to bed, but I suspect the answer is that the two clocks tick at the same rate, in the sense that there is a one to one correspondence between their ticks; however, if observers at P and Q timed the intervals between their local ticks with their watches, they would get different results. I'll sleep on that but please share your thoughts in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

At any given time, an observer inside the ship can be momentarily in free fall, and be an inertial comoving observer. The picture below can be used to understand what is going on, (it is for much bigger distances and time, but the idea is the same).

This observer is in position $1$ of the graph at the x-axis ($t = 0$). The bottom position is $0,5$ and the top position $2$. As top and bottom part has (momentarily) zero speed, the clocks can be synchronized, and are ticking at the same rate at $t=0$ for this frame.

But after any time interval $\delta t$, as the rocket is accelerating, this inertial frame is no more comoving, and the green straight line shows that the bottom clock (yellow hyperbola) measures a smaller time than the top clock (red hyperbola). So the clocks will be out of sync, and the top clock runs faster.

But note that any other observer accelerating with the rocket, (let's say following blue hyperbola for our inertial observer), can repeat the experience of be in free fall inside the rocket, and be momentarily comoving. For this new inertial frame, the graph is back again at the x-axis, where its position is $1$. And the clocks will be momentarily synchronized.

As this experience can be repeated at any time for an observed travelling inside the rocket, and accelerating with it, both clocks are syncronized, provided that the procedure of "falling" be followed just at the moment of checking the readings of clocks. Of course, the smaller is the distance between bottom and top, and the smaller the acceleration, the difference of being "falling" or not during the check is less meaningful for the accuracity of the check.

[image]

Comment: Claudio Saspinski: _"top and bottom part has (momentarily) zero speed"_ -- Yes, FWIW: Any inertial frame momentarily co-moving with the top $P$ is simultaneously momentarily co-moving with the floor $Q$. _"the clocks can be synchronized [...] And the clocks will be momentarily synchronized."_ -- All indications under consideration, i.e. included in the union $\mathcal P \cup \mathcal Q$ belong to events which are pairwise either lightlike or timelike separated from each other. (In other words: Please address the specificly prescribed clocks $\mathfrak P$ and $\mathfrak Q$ of my OP question.)

Comment: Claudio Saspinski: _"the bottom clock [...] measures a smaller time than the top clock"_ -- Specificly, for either clock: **from which** indication, **until which** indication ?? Do you (at least) confirm the strict inequality (which is indeed relevant for answering the OP question): 
$$ \left( \frac{\tau^P_{(\circledR \, Q \, \circledR \, P)}}{\tau^Q_{(\circledR \, P \, \circledR \, Q)}} \right) \gt 1 $$
for the mutual ping durations of top $P$ and floor $Q$ ? Also note: The question is "Which clock ticked faster?", i.e. about clock rates (even "tick rates"); not "Which clock ran ahead?".

Answer (score -1):

The average rate of a (generic) clock, $\mathfrak A \equiv (\mathcal A, t_{\mathfrak A})$, between any two (distinct) of its indications $A_J, A_K \in \mathcal A$ is ([defined as](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/318804/what-exactly-is-meant-by-clock-rate-in-the-theory-of-relativity)) the ratio

$$ f^{\mathfrak A}_{[ \, J, \, K \, ]} := \frac{\left(t_{\mathfrak A}[ \, A_K \, ] - t_{\mathfrak A}[ \, A_J \, ]\right)}{\tau^A_{[ \, J, \, K \, ]}} $$

- of the difference of the (real-number valued) readings, $t_{\mathfrak A}[ \, A_K \, ]$ and $t_{\mathfrak A}[ \, A_J \, ]$ which were assigned to the indications $A_K$, and $A_J$, respectively; and
- $A$'s duration $\tau^A_{[ \, J, \, K \, ]}$ from its indication $A_J$ until its indication $A_K$.

Applied to clock $\mathfrak P$ as specified in the OP question we obtain

$\Large f^{\mathfrak P}_{[ \, \ast, \, \, \circledR \, Q \, \circledR \, P \ast \, ]} = \huge \frac{(1 - 0)}{\tau^P_{[ \, \ast, \, \, \circledR \, Q \, \circledR \, P \ast \, ]}} = \frac{1}{\tau^P_{(\circledR \, Q \, \circledR \, P)}}$,

$\Large f^{\mathfrak P}_{[ \, \ast, \, \, \circledR \, Q \, \circledR \, P \, \circledR \, Q \, \circledR \, P \ast \, ]} = \huge \frac{(2 - 0)}{\tau^P_{[ \, \ast, \, \, \circledR \, Q \, \circledR \, P \, \circledR \, Q \, \circledR \, P \ast \, ]}} = \frac{2}{2 \, \tau^P_{(\circledR \, Q \, \circledR \, P)}} = \frac{1}{\tau^P_{(\circledR \, Q \, \circledR \, P)}}$,

$\Large f^{\mathfrak P}_{[ \, \circledR \, Q \, \circledR \, P \ast, \, \, \circledR \, Q \, \circledR \, P \, \circledR \, Q \, \circledR \, P \ast \, ]} = \huge \frac{(2 - 1)}{\tau^P_{[ \, \circledR \, Q \, \circledR \, P \ast, \, \, \circledR \, Q \, \circledR \, P \, \circledR \, Q \, \circledR \, P \ast \, ]}} = \frac{1}{\tau^P_{(\circledR \, Q \, \circledR \, P)}}$,

and so on.
All average clock rates of clock $\mathfrak P$, between any pair of (distinct) indications of set $\mathcal P$, have equal value, $\frac{1}{\tau^P_{(\circledR \, Q \, \circledR \, P)}}$, because $P$'s duration from any one of its tick indications until its next following tick indication is always $P$'s constant ping duration wrt. Q, i.e. $\tau^P_{(\circledR \, Q \, \circledR \, P)}$.

Consequently, clock $\mathfrak P$ is characterized by one constant rate value, i.e. $\Large f^{\mathfrak P} := \frac{1}{\tau^P_{(\circledR \, Q \, \circledR \, P)}}$;
and clock $\mathfrak P$ is therefore a so-called good clock, and in particular an [ideal clock in the sense of Gourgoulhon](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Special_Relativity_in_General_Frames/N4HBBAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover).

Likewise, all average clock rates of clock $\mathfrak Q$, between any pair of (distinct) indications of set $\mathcal Q$, have equal value, $\frac{1}{\tau^Q_{(\circledR \, P \, \circledR \, Q)}}$, because $Q$'s duration from any one of its tick indications until its next following tick indication is always $Q$'s constant ping duration wrt. P, i.e. $\tau^Q_{(\circledR \, P \, \circledR \, Q)}$.

And, consequently, clock $\mathfrak Q$ is also characterized by one constant rate value, i.e. $\Large f^{\mathfrak Q} := \frac{1}{\tau^Q_{(\circledR \, P \, \circledR \, Q)}}$;
and clock $\mathfrak Q$ is therefore also a good clock, and in particular an ideal clock.

Also, both these rates, $f^{\mathfrak P}$ and $f^{\mathfrak Q}$, have non-zero values. Therefore, in order to compare these two rates to each other, their ratio can be evaluated:

$$ \left( \frac{f^{\mathfrak Q}}{f^{\mathfrak P}} \right) = \left( \frac{\tau^P_{(\circledR \, Q \, \circledR \, P)}}{\tau^Q_{(\circledR \, P \, \circledR \, Q)}} \right).$$

Due to the prescribed setup holds

$$ \left( \frac{\tau^P_{(\circledR \, Q \, \circledR \, P)}}{\tau^Q_{(\circledR \, P \, \circledR \, Q)}} \right) \gt 1,$$

therefore also

$$ \left( \frac{f^{\mathfrak Q}}{f^{\mathfrak P}} \right) \gt 1.$$

Put in words: **clock $\mathfrak Q$**, which was produced by counting the successive ping indications of the rocket floor $Q$ (as its ticks), **had a larger ticking rate than clock $\mathfrak P$**, which was produced by counting the successive ping indications of the rocket top $P$ (as its ticks).

Or in other words: **clock $\mathfrak Q$ had been ticking faster than clock $\mathfrak P$**.

Comment: @Marco Ocram: _"[...] if observers at $P$ and $Q$ timed the intervals between their local ticks with their watches [...]"_ -- What's keeping us from granting rocket top $P$ and floor $Q$ themselves all relevant _"observer"_ abilities, for the thought-experimental description of the setup ?? And what could additional watches/clocks contribute while the OP question asks only about $\mathfrak P$ and $\mathfrak Q$ ?? (Admitteldly, determining the "geometric-kinematic requirements" and in particular the ratio of ping durations takes an entire reference system. But these were given with the OP.)