# The "Proper Time Experiments" of C. O. Alley et al.: Did the airborne clocks run longer than the groundbased clocks (rather than running faster)?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, experimental-physics, terminology

Description and results of the so-called ["proper time experiments"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22proper+time+experiments%22+%22patuxent+naval%22) which were carried out 1975-76 based at the [Patuxent Naval Air Test Center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naval_Air_Station_Patuxent_River), a.k.a. "the Maryland experiment", are widely known through the articles of [C. O. Alley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carroll_Alley); such as

- [[1] *"Relativity and Clocks"* (p. 17 ff.)](http://user.it.uu.se/%7Emarlu734/relativity/Alley1979-relativity_and_clocks.pdf) (as a primary resource), or
- [[2] *"Introduction to some fundamental concepts ..."* (p. 708 ff.)](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19820012654/downloads/19820012654.pdf) (as a *"tutorial lecture"*).

Alley presents certain *"proper time integrals"* for airborne clocks, and for ground clocks, as *"prediction of general relativity"* ([1], p. 17); and he reports ([2], p. 709): *"We would accumulate, during one of these flights, a typical time difference of about 50 nanoseconds. These measurements were in good agreement with the proper time integral. The time difference between the airborne and ground clocks would be given by integrals of this sort."*.

Alley's presentation of quantitative results, as well as further discussions, are then stated in terms of *"predicted effect"* alias *"calculated effect (GR)"* (namely the difference  $\tau_A - \tau_G$ between *"proper time integral"* values of airborne and of ground clocks); and *"measured effect"* (which apparently involves comparison of readings of certain clocks; especially *"pulse comparisons which were made when the plane was on the ground as well as in the air"*) ([1] p. 21).

Referring to the specific flight of November 22, 1975), Alley quantifies the *"predicted effect"* as
$$\tau_A - \tau_G = (47.1 \pm 0.25)~{\rm ns}$$
for a flight lasting (approximately) $\tau_A \approx \tau_G \approx 54'000~{\rm s}$.

Analyzing five flights, the ratio between these *"effects"* is found consistent (within uncertainty of less than 2 percent) with $1$. In conclusion ([1] p. 22), Alley only adds a rather abstract statement: *"The measured behavior of macroscopic clocks in air-craft flights - a "human scale" type of situation - exhibits the remarkable properties of Einsteinian time within the accuracy of measurement of about $1~\%$ !"*.

**My question:**

Referring specificly to the flight of  November 22, 1975, is it correct that in this experimental trial:

$$ \left( \frac{ \tau_A }{ \tau_G } \right) - 1 \approx 0.87 \times 10^{-12} $$

and that within the accuracy of measurement:

$$ \left( \frac{ \tau_A }{ \tau_G } \right) - 1 \gt 0.8 \times 10^{-12} $$

?

If so, is this correctly verbalized as stating that in this experimental trial
"the airborne clocks flew, and ran, **longer** than the groundbased clocks remained grounded, and ran, while the plane was in the air" ?

Also: Could conclusions be drawn about the comparison of rates of airborne and of groundbased clocks ?
Especially:
Did these clocks run at equal rates, i.e. **equally fast**, within the accuracy of measurement, in this experimental trial ?

---

**Edit** (Note in view of the first answer having been submitted):

Since above I've been asking about (comparison of) rates of clocks in the experiment described above, I can further specify that my question is meant to ask about the **relevant** rates of the **relevant** clocks.

As C. O. Alley states (p. 18 of  article [1] linked above):
*"Intercomparison of the epochs of the zero crossings of the $5~{\rm MHz}$ clock output was made [...]."*, and they contribute to the (relevant) plot top-right on p. 21: *"The direct comparison measurements of the $5~{\rm MHz}$ clock phases before and after the flight are shown [...] along with the laser pulse comparisons which were made when the plane was on the ground as well as in the air."* (Where this plot also depicts the *"predicted effect"*.)

Unfortunately, article [1] doesn't introduce a symbol for these epochs of the zero crossings of the $5~{\rm MHz}$ clock outputs of airborne clocks, or of groundbased clocks, respectively. Matching the notation above, let's symbolize their values as $t^{(5~{\rm MHz})}_A$ and $t^{(5~{\rm MHz})}_B$, resp.

For the purpose of my question, the relevant rates are accordingly the average rates

- of the airborne clocks:
  $$ \overline{f^{(5~{\rm MHz})}_A} := \left( \frac{(t^{(5~{\rm MHz})}_A[ \, \text{arrival} \, ] - t^{(5~{\rm MHz})}_A[ \, \text{departure} \, ])}{\tau_A} \right)$$
- and of the groundbased clocks:
  $$ \overline{f^{(5~{\rm MHz})}_G} := \left( \frac{(t^{(5~{\rm MHz})}_G[ \, \text{arrival} \, ] - t^{(5~{\rm MHz})}_G[ \, \text{departure} \, ])}{\tau_G} \right)$$
  .

Note that the designation $"5~{\rm MHz}"$ is meant only nominally; as a label, not necessarily corresponding an actual exact value.
Accordingly, in terms of these relevant rates, my question can be restated more quantitatively as

- whether within the accuracy of measurement:

$$ \text{Abs} \Bigg[ \, \left( \frac{ \overline{f^{(5~{\rm MHz})}_A } }{ \overline{f^{(5~{\rm MHz})}_G} } \right)  - 1 \, \Bigg] \gt 0.8 \times 10^{-12} $$

- or whether instead, within the accuracy of measurement, say:

$$ \text{Abs} \Bigg[ \, \left( \frac{ \overline{f^{(5~{\rm MHz})}_A } }{ \overline{f^{(5~{\rm MHz})}_G} } \right) - 1 \, \Bigg] \lt 0.05 \times 10^{-12} $$

- or neither.

Answer (score 1):

Given two clocks $A$ and $B$, I would say

- If $\frac{\tau_A}{\tau_B} - 1 > 0$, then $\tau_A > \tau_B$, so clock $A$ runs *slower* than clock $B$.
- If $\frac{\tau_A}{\tau_B} - 1 < 0$, then clock $A$ runs *faster* than clock $B$.
- If $\frac{\tau_A}{\tau_B} - 1 = 0$, then clock $A$ runs *at the same rate* as clock $B$.

I also want to say something about terminology. Consider the first case, where $\tau_A > \tau_B$ ($A$ runs slower than $B$). To me, the clock running "longer" than clock $B$ captures the idea that $\tau_A > \tau_B$, but using the word "slower" to describe this point is more standard in physics. I also think using the word "longer" can be misleading, since the reason that $\tau_A > \tau_B$ is not simply that we left $\tau_A$ run for extra time; while what is really going on is that the *rate* at which time passed for clock $A$ was different than for clock $B$.

With these preliminaries out of the way, let's turn to your questions.

> Referring specificly to the flight of November 22, 1975, is it correct that in this experimental trial:
> $$\frac{\tau_A}{\tau_G} -1 \approx 0.87×10−12 $$

Yes, using $\left(4.71 \times 10^{-8}\ {\rm s}\right)/\left(5.4\times 10^{4}\ {\rm s}\right) = 0.87 \times 10^{-12}.$

> If so, is this correctly verbalized as stating that in this experimental trial "the airborne clocks flew, and ran, longer than the groundbased clocks remained grounded, and ran, while the plane was in the air" ?

Sure, with the caveats in my comment on terminology above.

> Also: Could conclusions be drawn about the comparison of rates of airborne and of groundbased clocks ?

Yes. The airborne clock runs slower than the ground-based clock.

> Did these clocks run at equal rates, i.e. equally fast, within the accuracy of measurement, in this experimental trial ?

No, since $\frac{\tau_A}{\tau_G} - 1 \neq 0$ (and indeed is not zero within the experimental uncertainty).

---

You don't say this in your question, but it sounds like you may be thinking the authors can't conclude the rates at which the clocks accumulate time are different, because they did not do a fair comparison of how much time elapsed on the two clocks.

If that is the case, let me just note:

- they obtain an experimental result that agrees very well with the prediction of general relativity, and that prediction *does* say the rate at which the clocks change is different.
- a detailed description of how the comparison was made, and how the systematic uncertainties were estimated, is given in pages 18-22 of your Ref 1. In particular, note that comparisons between the ground and airborne clocks were made *while the plane was in the air*. So it's not just the case that $\tau_A > \tau_G$ because the airborne clock was running for additional time, in a trivial sense.

Comment: An excellent answer. Regarding terminology, describing moving clocks as 'running slow' is the cause of most of the misunderstandings of SR on this website. What we really mean is that a moving clock accurately measures a shorter time interval- saying that it runs slow implies that it is impaired in some way by motion, causing it to under-report time. Indeed, in at least once respect @user12262 is right to say the clocks tick at the same rate, in that they each record a second for each second of elapsed time they experience.

Comment: By analogy, if two pedometers are used to measure different paths between two points, and we find that the reading on one is less than the reading on the other, we naturally say that one path was shorter than the other- we do no say that one of the pedometers has run slow.

Comment: Andrew: _"To me, [$A$] running "longer" than [$B$] captures the idea that $\tau_A \gt \tau_B$"_ -- Excellent! _"but using the word "slower" to describe this point is more standard in physics."_ -- I disagree: "slower" is merely in sloppy use for comparison of durations. Explicit discussion of rates alongside necessitates careful distinction between "shorter" vs. "slower" etc. (I'll add my answer accordingly.) _"[...] rates [...]"_  -- Please note the recent "Edit" of my question. _"that the rate at which time passed for clock $A$ was different than for clock $B$"_ -- What's that ?!?? ...

Comment: @MarcoOcram Thanks for your comment. Of course I agree each clock runs "normally" in its own frame. I suppose I was taking it for granted that, since this question is about GR, the SR meaning of the phrase was understood. Namely, that in A's frame, if B moves relative to A, B's clock will appear to A to run slower than A's clock. The rate of advance of B's clock, using A's clock as a standard, is slow, hence "moving clocks run slow." I am applying the same logic to the GR case. From the point of view of the ground-based clock, the airborne clock runs slow.

Comment: I also think the pedometer analogy has a lot of potential to be misunderstood. It's not the case that the experimentalists were sloppy, and that $\tau_A>\tau_G$ simply because they let the airplane take a longer path through space. The astounding result was that for the airborne clock, a longer amount of proper time elapsed through the path in space*time*. Maybe there's no perfect way to convey that idea in words without math, but I think conveying this point is the difficulty we are facing.

Comment: @user12262 I think we are getting to the crux of the issue. See my comment to MarcoOcram. What I am saying is that the rate at which the airborne clock measures one second, *using the ground-based clock as a reference*, is slower than 1 ground-second / 1 ground-second. You have to be a bit careful in GR about what it means to compare clocks at different points in a gravitational field. But the experimental procedure is defined in the paper and is sensible: a laser from the plane to the ground regularly transmits the reading on the plane's clock. These readings are compared to the ground clock.

Comment: Andrew: _"The astounding result was that for the airborne clock, a longer amount of proper time elapsed through the path in spacetime."_ -- I fully agree that relativistic "treatment" is in order. But I reject to be "astounded" by that what you call _"result"_ (namely, by the "flyer duration" $\tau_A$ being larger/longer than the "spectator duration" $\tau_G$). Instead, that's perfectly usual and even prescribed by the "flight schedule", as part of the experimental setup. I reject the naive (perhaps "Newtonian"?) attitude and any correspondingly naive, improper, inapplicable language.

Comment: @user12262 Here are what I see as the main experimental facts. An airbone atomic clock makes a record at regular time intervals (let's say it is every second for simplicity). These records are transmitted via a laser to the ground, and compared with the records produced by identical clock. Newtonian gravity would predict that the records received from the plane arrive at the same rate as records are produced by the ground clock. GR predicts the plane records will arrive at a slower rate. The data support GR and rule out Newtonian gravity. Do you agree with that?

Comment: If we agree on the experimental facts, and that they support Newtonian gravity and not GR, then that's good enough for me -- it's fine with me if you have a different set of words than the ones I used to express these points, I certainly don't claim to have the clearest explanation of all concepts. If we don't agree on the experimental facts, then it seems we have a more substantive issue, and I would be very interested to know specifically which part of my description of the experiment in the comment above you disagree with.

Comment: Andrew: _"exp. facts"_ -- Nom. 5 MHz output, every 10^9 ticks, timestamped and rapidly sent off, timestamped at the receiver/reflector, timestamped at return. _"Newtonian gravity would predict [...]"_  -- The **GR**-based model of planes over Chesapeake Bay, along with the flight plan, predict $\tau A / \tau G = 1 + 0.87 \times 10^{-12}$. Applying limits $v/c \rightarrow 0$ and $g \, h /c^2 \rightarrow 0$ then "predicts" $\tau A / \tau G = 1$. Forget _"Newtonian"_ whatever, as such! _"The data support GR [...]"_ -- The results support **models**; incl. **RT**-based models of "atomic physics".

Comment: @user12262 *"The GR-based model of planes over Chesapeake Bay, along with the flight plan, predict /=1+0.87×10−12. Applying limits /→0 and ℎ/2→0 then "predicts" /=1."* -- Sounds like we agree on the main points. That's good enough for me!

Comment: Andrew: _"[...] the plane records will arrive at a slower rate."_ -- The plane-record-reception rate of ground-based receivers is (generally) **larger than** the corresponding record-generation rate of the plane. Please note that my OP question is (equivalently) about comparing the average record-generation rate of the plane to the average record-generation rate of a ground-based sender. _"GR predicts"_ -- Rather: GR provides the methodology how to compare record-generation rates (where the ratios between reception rates and generation rates also play a role). Agreed?

Comment: @user12262 I don't understand how the "plane-record-reception rate of ground-based receivers" can be compared with the "record-generation rate of the plane." All comparisons must be done in the same location -- either on the ground, or in the plane. The experiment is set up so that a clock on the plane records time, and these time records are transmitted to the ground. The records received on the ground, can be compared to a clock on the ground, because the received records and the ground clock are all in the same location. You could also transmit information from the ground to the plane (...)

Comment: (...) although that isn't how this particular experiment was actually done. So if we are being careful about what experimental quantities GR makes statements about, the only comparisons you can make are between the plane-record-reception rate and the record-generation rate on the ground, **OR** between the ground-record-reception rate and the record-generation rate on the plane. Ref 1 shows that the plane-record-reception rate of ground-based receivers is smaller than the ground-record-generation rate of ground-based clocks.

Answer (score 0):

### ​ Remarks on terminology

Duration is an **extensive** quantity. Comparing durations, such as $\tau_A$ to $\tau_G$ it is therefore appropriate to speak of the larger also as "the longer", and of the lesser as "the shorter".

Further, since any duration is generally **of** some specific identifiable participant, such as $\tau_A$ being the duration **of** the airborne clocks (as well as **of** other constituents of the plane) from departure until arrival, and $\tau_G$ being the duration **of** the groundbased clocks (as well as of others groundbased "spectators") from witnessing the plane leaving, until witnessing the plane having returned, one can be said to have "taken longer" that another, if applicable.

In contrast, rate is an **intensive** quantity. In analogy to language concerning speed, someone who undergoes a certain process at larger rate (than someone else) is said to be "(acting) faster", "quicker" (than the other; who is in turn termed "slower", "more leisurely" etc.).

### ​ Comparison of average rates $\overline{f^{(5~{\rm MHz})}_A}$ and $\overline{f^{(5~{\rm MHz})}_G}$

C. O. Alley, [1] p. 22, reports the result as

$$ \frac{\text{Measured effect}}{\text{Calculated Effect (General relativity)}} = 0.987 \pm 0.016, $$

i.e. approximately the result value $1$, which is understood as being "consistent with the prediction".

The $\text{Calculated Effect (General relativity)}$, a.k.a. the $\text{Predicted Effect}$, is the difference of (calculated) durations $\tau_A$ and $\tau_G$, with the value given (in the top-right plot on p. 21) as $(47.1 \pm 0.25)~{\rm ns}$.

An explicit symbolic expression of the $\text{Measured effect}$ (which Alley doesn't give, unfortunately) is therefore arguably

$$\text{Measured effect} := \tau_G \, \left( \frac{\tau_A \, \overline{f^{(5~{\rm MHz})}_A}}{\tau_G \, \overline{f^{(5~{\rm MHz})}_G}} - 1 \right).$$

The result statement
$$\frac{\text{Measured effect}}{\text{Calculated Effect (General relativity)}} \approx 1 \pm 0.02 $$

is thereby equivalent to

$$\frac{\tau_G \, \left( \frac{\tau_A \, \overline{f^{(5~{\rm MHz})}_A}}{\tau_G \, \overline{f^{(5~{\rm MHz})}_G}} - 1 \right)}{(\tau_A - \tau_G)} \approx 1 \pm 0.02 ,$$

$$ \left( \frac{\tau_A \, \overline{f^{(5~{\rm MHz})}_A}}{\tau_G \, \overline{f^{(5~{\rm MHz})}_G}} - 1 \right) \approx (0.87 \times 10^{-12}) \, (1 \pm 0.02), $$

$$\left( \frac{\tau_A \, \overline{f^{(5~{\rm MHz})}_A}}{\tau_G \, \overline{f^{(5~{\rm MHz})}_G}} \right) \approx 1 + (0.87 \times 10^{-12}) \, (1 \pm 0.02),$$

$$\left( \frac{\overline{f^{(5~{\rm MHz})}_A}}{\overline{f^{(5~{\rm MHz})}_G}} \right) \approx \frac{1 + (0.87 \times 10^{-12}) \, (1 \pm 0.02)}{1 + (0.87 \times 10^{-12})},$$

$$\left( \frac{\overline{f^{(5~{\rm MHz})}_A}}{\overline{f^{(5~{\rm MHz})}_G}} \right) \approx 1 \pm (0.02) \, (0.87 \times 10^{-12}),$$

i.e. these two average rates are much closer to each other than the (already very close) two durations $\tau_A$ and $\tau_G$ are to each other.

Comment: @Andrew: _I don't understand how the "plane-record-reception rate of ground-based receivers" can be compared with the "record-generation rate of the plane."_ -- No kidding?? See: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/318804/what-exactly-is-meant-by-clock-rate-in-the-theory-of-relativity (where, in physics, "What is meant by?" is of course closely related to "How to measure?"). _"All comparisons must be done in the same location"_ -- No. The point is that GR allows to compare durations (i.e. measure duration ratios) in general; such as the value of ratio $\tau_A / \tau_G$ as well.